# Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation on cloned database

Tags: sql-server

I have a database on live, I cloned it on my machine and tried executing one store procedure but it is giving me the following error

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between
>   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" 
>       and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

I have seen many solutions but just unsure of one thing which is, it doesn't throw this error on the main database but on cloned one it is. What can be the reason and how to resolve?

Comment: Depends on what technology you used to "clone" it. Scripts? Backup/restore? If scripts, how where these scripts generated? If Management Studio, did you use the "advanced" scripting options to include collations?

Comment: I  did "BackUp" .

Comment: Most likely the procedure uses temporary tables, which use the collation of TempDB by default (which in turn uses the instance default collation), so even if the two databases have the same collation, if the two instances don't you could end up with collation issues.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I am still unsure how to resolve that?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/161038/7257